# Are answers being posted as comments?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if it's just me, but I've been seeing a lot of answers that are being posted in comments. Nothing wrong with that, per se, but I would like to be able to upvote that as an answer that gives the commenter more rep.

[Example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/45510/6415)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Encouraging them to post it as an answer is an excellent way to remedy this.

Then there is Jeff's definitive answer:

[image: Jeff's Comment]

Comment: or, stealing it and posting it as an answer yourself (assuming the Q is valid) -- this is allowed and even encouraged, but do mention the comment owner in your answer. *.. AND THEN RAKE IN THOSE SWEET HOT VOTES!!*

Comment: way to steal the comment :)

Comment: 8 pixels less and you wouldn't have that funky anti-aliasing on the comment screenshot

Comment: @Renesis: I tried to trim it, let me go at it again.

Answer (score 13):

1. I usually put an answer as a comment when the question is likely to be closed (or when I vote to close) but want to help the OP anyway.
2. I also put an answer as a comment when I feel my answer does not deserve the exposure of an answer but may help the OP anyway.
3. Finally, I use comment to put some humor sometimes that definitely doesn't deserve to be made as an answer.

Comment: Perfect list - For me there is a sub-part of #2, where the answer is only a part answer or side-note (but may help the OP anyway)

Answer (score 6):

Comments as answers are becoming more common on some sites. This is a problem because once a comment-based answer is posted, most users will not feel compelled to provide a proper answer. The question then remains squarely in the 'unanswered' column. Besides, comments-as-answers cannot be vetted, and voted on properly so the best answers *don't* always appear on the top.

The comment authors should be asked to post their comment as an answer. Failing that, comment-based answers are fair game. Post the answer yourself and flag the errant comment for removal.

Answer (score 4):

I frequently use comments as answers if I think that the question doesn't meet our guidelines, but I feel like responding anyway. However, I usually mention that I don't think it meets the guidelines in my comment.

Comment: +1 for being what I was going to write.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it the answers in comments are usually poor quality and not of significant value. They detract from using comments to get to the real question. 
I have also see controversial answers posted in comments, possibly as you cannot be down voted and loose points for a comment.  I feel that they should be discouraged, and ideally comment able to be up/down voted and points allocated.